# Filter link to existing content suggestion

Tags: php, filters, links

How can i filter the link given in "link to existing content".

Eg:[image]

As in the above image. I just want WSP BANNER TO BE SHOWN.

where WSP BANNER & CALENDAR are custom POST types

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: So you want to filter the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are no ready filters available for this purpose. A [ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21033) has been posted for the request.Lets hope we get one soon.

Instead of hardcoding your custom post types its better to create a filter hook and use it

Till then you can create your own filter.

Open includes/class-wp-editor.php and make folowing changes at line no 712

```
$pt_names = apply_filters('custom_insert_link_suggestion_filter',array_keys( $pts ));
```

we just added a new filter instead of getting all the public post types

Then in your theme add following code to filter the internal link custom post type

```
function my_filter_function($allowed_post_types)
{


if( condition chek)
{
         return array('page','your custom post types');
}


}
add_filter('custom_insert_link_suggestion_filter','my_filter_function',10,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's very very urgent, you may be want to edit class-wp-editor line 711 to

```
$pts = get_post_types( array( 'name' => 'your_post_type','public' => true ), 'objects' );
```

, **otherwise leave AS IS**

Comment: I would highly suggest not to edit the core files, unless it can save your job ;)

Comment: as I said, if very very urgent :D

Comment: Yep correct! :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. Ya its clients requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file `class-wp-editor.php`, line no. 742 onwards. The list doesn't have any filters applied to it. So I guess you can't change it!

More, in the same file, line no. 689, the function `wp_link_query` is called via an AJAX request for getting this list, it too doesn't have any filters to change the post types!

Hence, you have to live with it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin for that. You can download it [here from the plugin repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/b09-link-to-existing-content/).

Install it and then put this filter in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( "link_to_existing_content_post_types", "my_link_to_existing_content_post_types" );
function my_link_to_existing_content_post_types( $post_types ) {  
    $post_types = array( "post", "page" );
    return $post_types;
}
```

This plugin also has the functionality to replace internal links with shortcodes. If you don't want to use this, deactivate it like this:

```
add_filter( "link_to_existing_content_use_shortcode", "disable_link_to_existing_content_shortcode" );
function disable_link_to_existing_content_shortcode() {
    return false;
}
```

Full instructions can be found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/b09-link-to-existing-content/faq/